# Пропали папки Зависимости в проекте Visual C++ Win32

Tags: visual-studio-2015

При создание пустого проекта пропали папки **"Зависимости"**. Как их вернуть? Раньше когда Я создавал проект они присутствовали, а сейчас их нету.

Проблема возникла после переустановки компонентов visual c++

[image: Visual C++ Win32 Console Empty Project]